# При вставке в таблицу значений JSON массива ошибка: ORA-40573: Invalid use of PL/SQL JSON object type

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица:

```
create table tab (name varchar2 (8), type varchar2 (8));
```

Нужно вставить в неё значения JSON массива. Пробую так:

```
DECLARE
    l_stuff json_array_t;
BEGIN
    l_stuff := json_array_t ('["Stirfry", "Yogurt", "Apple"] ');  
    FOR indx IN 0 .. l_stuff.get_size - 1 LOOP
        INSERT INTO tab (name, type) VALUES(l_stuff.get_string(indx), 'TEXT');
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> Error report -
> ORA-40573: Invalid use of PL/SQL JSON object type.
> ORA-06512: at line 6

Как можно её обойти или исправить?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to convert json to columns and rows with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67535043) от участника [@Menja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10465754/menja)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67535043

Answer (score 3):

Это все ещё остающийся открытым, насколько мне известно, [баг](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2490027_1.html).

Чтобы обойти эту проблему, можно сначала присвоить значение переменной:

```
DECLARE
    l_stuff json_array_t;
    l_name  tab.name%type;
BEGIN
    l_stuff := json_array_t ('["Stirfry", "Yogurt", "Apple"] ');  
    FOR indx IN 0 .. (l_stuff.get_size - 1) LOOP
        -- assigfn to variable - bug 28901431 
        l_name := l_stuff.get_string(indx);
        INSERT INTO tab (name, type) VALUES (l_name, 'TEXT');
   END LOOP;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1fb337130e29f445df6b59559ed4b896)

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535420) от участника [@Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole)</sub>

Comment: @MaxU Уменя сейчас нет доступа к MOS, если у вас есть, не могли бы вы посмотреть по ссылке на баг, что там пишут. Что-то я не уверен, что это баг.

Answer (score 3):

Для обхода ошибки можно сначала преобразовать JSON массив в обычный PL/SQL массив, а затем с ним сделать массовую вставку.

Вот [воспроизводимый пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=65b553320ca3c636d74ad2e5b97ddedb):

```
create table tab (name varchar2 (8), type varchar2 (8))
/
declare
    type namelist is table of varchar2(8) index by pls_integer;
    names namelist;
    arr json_array_t := json_array_t ('["Stirfry", "Yogurt", "Apple"]');
begin
    for idx in 1..arr.get_size loop 
        names(idx) := arr.get_string(idx-1);
    end loop;
    forall idx in indices of names
        insert into tab (name, type) values (names(idx), 'TEXT');
end;
/
```

Сам запрос и его результат:

```
select * from tab
/
NAME     TYPE    
-------- --------
Stirfry  TEXT    
Yogurt   TEXT    
Apple    TEXT
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67545896) от участника [@0xdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6571020/0xdb)</sub>